# Plot discrete points as curves with crossing

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list of [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TokH1ZM9ltrTUHPNf_OLDqD4-dG-xYnq/view?usp=sharing) in the form of {x,y} (30K only). The discrete data give two curves with a cross point.

```
pts = ToExpression /@ Import["~\\testdata.csv"];
ListPlot[pts, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-1, 0.1}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

[image]

**My goal:**

I would like to **plot 2 independent smooth curves according to these points in one graphic as follows.** The 2 curves are expected based on their physical meaning.

[image]

**My trial:**

1. I have tried to separate the two curves using the `Unshuffle` function provided by @Victor K. in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278064/how-to-plot-root-curves-from-topological-changing-curves/278658?noredirect=1#comment696315_278658), but it seems that when the two curves are crossing, that code cannot separate them as expected.

   {LstA, LstB} = Unshuffle[pts];
   unshufflePlot = ListPlot[{LstA, LstB}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Green},
   PlotRange -> {{1, 1.5}, {-0.4, -0.15}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 0.6]

[image]

2. I also tried `FindCurvePath`, which even only gives a small part of the plot...

   curves = FindCurvePath[pts];
   FindCurvePlot = ListLinePlot[pts[[curves[[1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TokH1ZM9ltrTUHPNf_OLDqD4-dG-xYnq/view?usp=sharing)]]], PlotRange -> {{1, 1.5}, {-0.4, -0.15}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, AspectRatio -> 0.6]

[image]

3. As suggested by @Domen, I tried the `findCurves` function in [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256942/how-to-extract-different-curves-from-a-mixed-dataset), however, it still cannot separate the different curves from the mixed dataset. What it gives is some mixed curves depending on the value of eps in `findCurves`.

Now, I have no idea to solve this problem. Can someone give some suggestions? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your question is very similar to this [Q](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146079/10397)&[A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146105/10397) have you tried the approach on those answers?

Comment: @Jsxs Your question has been flagged as a duplicate. Please [edit] your question to explain how is it different from the other similar questions on the site. Otherwise you risk having the question closed, unable to receive further answers.

Comment: @rhermans, thank you for your suggestion. I have tested with the answer in the post you provided, that method gives two curves as a whole. Please also see my update.

Comment: *"it still cannot separate the different curves from the mixed dataset"* is not enough, you have to show your diligence. Please explain what fails and how, show your code attempts, show the outputs. You are making it hard to help you.

Comment: @jsxs, using [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/256970/75628) from question provided above as ``curves = findCurves[data, .03]`` produces [desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPeWo.png).

Answer (score 1):

Your data has a simple structure with some flaws. The main feature is that there is always one point of one curve and then a point of the other curve. Therefore, I think one should exploit this feature.

However, there are some irregularities tat need fixing. The first 6 point belong exclusively to curve 2. Then there are 3 points without a partner on the other curve, namely point no.: 351,380,381. Further from point no.: 878 the curves are reversed.

To fix this, we may first reverse the order of the points from point no:. 878 on:

```
pts[[878 ;;]] = Transpose[Reverse /@ Partition[pts[[878 ;;]], 2]];
```

Then we can delete the singular points:

```
pts = Delete[pts, {{351}, {980}, {981}}];
```

Finally we may disassemble the points by taking the first 6 points:

```
d0 = dat[[;; 6]];
```

Then we partition the rest of the points according to the 2 curves:

```
{d1, d2} = Transpose[Partition[pts[[7 ;;]], 2]];
```

Then we add the first 6 points to curve 2:

```
d2 = Join[d0, d2];
```

Now we have the points separated into 2 curves:

```
ListLinePlot[{d1, d2}]
```

[image]

If you want functions, you can write:

```
f1= Interpolation[d1];
f2= Interpolation[d2];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

pts = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/testdata.csv", "Data"];

{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[pts[[All, 1]]]

(* {0., 2.995} *)
```

Use [`FindCurvePath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html) to separate the segments

```
pts4 = pts[[#]] & /@ FindCurvePath[pts];

ListLinePlot[pts4,
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.3, .4}]]
```

[image]

[`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) the line segments

```
pts2 = {Join[pts4[[1]], pts4[[3]]], Join[pts4[[2]], pts4[[4]]]};
```

Using [`FindFormula`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html) to fit the curves

```
funcs = FindFormula[#, x] & /@ pts2

(* {0.0176757 x - 0.419725 x^2 + 0.416205 x^3 - 0.292456 x^4 + 
     0.0928377 x^5 - 0.0106112 x^6, 
   -0.288809 + 0.0187772 x + 0.00952705 x^2 - 0.00298774 x^3} *)

Plot[funcs, {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

[image]